# Allow only AJAX requests in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am building an express app. I want the routes to be accessed only via AJAX requests. I see that it has something to deal with `X-Requested-With` header. But I don't know how I can blanket-ban all other requests. Does anyone have any idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a custom middleware to intercept all requests.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.xhr) {
    next()
  } else {
    res.status(400).end('400 Bad Request')
  }
})

// put your routes here
app.get('/', (_, res) => res.json("Hello world"))
```

Comment: express out of the box can listen to requests that don't conform to http?

Comment: @DanielLizik Yes, it is. The document at https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.xhr

Comment: ah i get it. i thought OP wanted to ignore non-http requests, I was confused.

Comment: That is `http` module's responsibility?

Comment: Note, this won't stop outside agents (postman, PHP, etc...) from masquerading as an Ajax call and directly accessing your server.